# Drop sorted row based on value count column

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
   year   id    
0  2019   x1
1  2012   x1
2  2017   x1
3  2013   x1
4  2018   x2
5  2012   x2
6  2013   x2
```

I want to filter my whole dataframe such that if there are more than 3 observations per id, the observation with the lowest year should be dropped.

In this case, the 1th row should be dropped.

```
   year   id    
0  2019   x1
1  2017   x1
2  2013   x1
3  2018   x2
4  2012   x2
5  2013   x2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['id','year'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('id').head(3)
print (df)
   year  id
0  2019  x1
2  2017  x1
3  2013  x1
4  2018  x2
6  2013  x2
5  2012  x2
```

If order should be same add [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['id','year'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('id').head(3).sort_index()
print (df)
   year  id
0  2019  x1
2  2017  x1
3  2013  x1
4  2018  x2
5  2012  x2
6  2013  x2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `GroupBy.nlargest`:

```
df = df.groupby('id')['year'].nlargest(3).reset_index().drop(columns='level_1')

   id  year
0  x1  2019
1  x1  2017
2  x1  2013
3  x2  2018
4  x2  2013
5  x2  2012
```

Make sure that `year` has an `int` dtype:

```
df['year'] = df['year'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a for loop for solving this problem (I love for Loops):

```
id_unique = df.id.unique()

df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)

for i in id_unique:
    df_new = pd.concat([df_new, df[df['id'] == i ].sort_values(['year'], ascending= [False]).head(3)], axis=0)
```

Comment: Maybe not the fastest, but +1 for creativity. Anything else you love, For Loop Berry?

Comment: Thank you Ylja ! I have to say there is nothing I love more than For Loops but a while ago while loops also conquered a little place in my heart !